# Get a logfile for a specific date

Tags: powershell, shell

I want to save in my computer "C:\logFiles" a specific date for logfile generated by program in another PC,
path that i will get from it the log file is "C:\Sut\Stat\03-2021.log"

Example : this file "C:\Sut\Stat\03-2021.Sutwin.log" contenant all the log of Mars month but i just want to get the log of last 7 Days from 19-03-2021 to 26-03-2021

I found this script in the internet but i doesn't work for me i need some help:

[Example of the file .log in the photo attached:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ttDp.png)

[Rest of image for the first screenshot :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn2xA.png)

1. my PC name : c01234
2. name of PC contenant log file : c06789
3. file that i will get from it the infos : 03-2021.Sutwin.log (exist in pc c06789)
4. i want to transfer the contents of just last 7 days in a folder in my PC c01234 with name Week11_LogFile

```
$log = "2015-05-09T06:39:34 Some information here

2015-05-09T06:40:34 Some information here
" -split "`n" | Where {$_.trim()}

#using max and min value for the example so all correct dates will comply
$upperLimit = [datetime]::MaxValue #replace with your own date
$lowerLimit = [datetime]::MinValue #replace with your own date

$log | foreach {
$dateAsText = ($_ -split '\s',2)[0]
try
{
$date = [datetime]::Parse($dateAsText)
if (($lowerLimit -lt $date) -and ($date -lt $upperLimit))
{
$_ #output the current item because it belongs to the requested time frame
}
}
catch [InvalidOperationException]
{
#date is malformed (maybe the line is empty or there is a typo), skip it
}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show a sample of `03-2021.Sutwin.log`'s contents and actual file names.

Comment: @vonPryz done i edit the question with adding a simple example from my log file

Comment: sorry for delay but doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 1):

Based on your images, your log files look like simple tab-delimited files.

Assuming that's the case, this should work:

```
# Import the data as a tab-delimited file and add a DateTime column with a parsed value
$LogData = Import-Csv $Log -Delimiter "`t" |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='DateTime';e={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date + $_.Time, 'dd. MMM yyHH:mm:ss', $null)}}

# Filter the data, drop the DateTime column, and write the output to a new tab-delimited file
$LogData | Where-Object { ($lowerLimit -lt $_.DateTime) -and ($_.DateTime -lt $upperLimit) } |
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty DateTime |
    Export-Csv $OutputFile -Delimiter "`t"
```

The primary drawback here is that on Windows Powershell (v5.1 and below) you can only export the data quoted. On Powershell 7 and higher you can use `-UseQuotes Never` to prevent the fields from being double quote identified if that's important.

The only other drawback is that if these log files are huge then it will take a long time to import and process them. You may be able to improve performance by making the above a one-liner like so:

```
Import-Csv $Log -Delimiter "`t" |
    Select-Object -Property *, @{n='DateTime';e={[datetime]::ParseExact($_.Date + $_.Time, 'dd. MMM yyHH:mm:ss', $null)}} |
    Where-Object { ($lowerLimit -lt $_.DateTime) -and ($_.DateTime -lt $upperLimit) } |
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty DateTime |
    Export-Csv $OutputFile -Delimiter "`t"
```

But if the log files are extremely large then you may run into unavoidable performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame your example of a line in the log file does not reveal the exact date format.
`2015-05-09` could be `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyy-dd-MM`, so I'm guessing it's `yyyy-MM-dd` in below code..

```
# this is the UNC path where the log file is to be found
# you need permissions of course to read that file from the remote computer
$remotePath = '\\c06789\C$\Sut\Stat\03-2021.log'  # or use the computers IP address instead of its name
$localPath  = 'C:\logFiles\Week11_LogFile.log'    # the output file

# set the start date for the week you are interested in
$startDate = Get-Date -Year 2021 -Month 3 -Day 19

# build an array of formatted dates for an entire week
$dates = for ($i = 0; $i -lt 7; $i++) { '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}' -f $startDate.AddDays($i) }
# create a regex string from that using an anchor '^' and the dates joined with regex OR '|'
$regex = '^({0})' -f ($dates -join '|')

# read the log file and select all lines starting with any of the dates in the regex
((Get-Content -Path $remotePath) | Select-String -Pattern $regex).Line | Set-Content -Path $localPath
```